# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column app_table.field does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, database-migration

I have a django app which is already in production. I added some new tables and new fields to existing tables and all went well in the feature branch, but when I merged it with the main branch then i got the following error: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column appname_table.field does not exist.

I have tried deleting migrations, running fake migrations and a lot of other stuff but it doesn't work out. It might be possible to delete database on local but not in production because already there is user data.

Comment: To be sure, have you ran both `python3 manage.py makemigrations` (either locally before pushing, or in production after pulling) and `python3 manage.py migrate` (has to be in production)?

Comment: Yes, while working on feature branch all migrations were run and migrated, then they were able to make the features.

but now after merging into main and running these. we are getting this error

Comment: "_I have tried deleting migrations, running fake migrations_" you should never delete / fake the migrations unless you are 100% sure you know what you are doing. Given we have no clue what and how exactly you did stuff I am voting to close this question. If you can share a [mre] with proper steps to reproduce your problem maybe we can help. As an advice what I'd try to fix the issue: 1) Revert to the git commit the database in prod is currently on. 2) Delete the local database 3) Apply migrations. 4) Switch to the commit with latest changes and try to figure out what went wrong from here.

Comment: In general if you are already in production you should never be deleting all the migrations. If they are not applied to production you can potentially delete the new ones.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat i only cut and paste the migrations temporarily, but did put them  back. the reason i'm not deleting the local db is that the app is already in prod, deleting local db might work out but what to do in prod. Secondly i also reverted my main from that merge so main stays clean

Comment: @AmeerHamza perform the above steps I mentioned locally. After step 3 your local database should be somewhat equivalent to what is was like before. Try to use it a bit and generate some data. After that you try to reproduce the problem you are currently facing and find out the actual cause of it.